# EF Code First: separate creation of objects in db with TFT inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, table-per-type

**Use-case example**

A user have registered on website (adding record to Users table). Then goes to email and  confirms registration. The confirmation link redirects to page with person edit form, a user fills the form and submits it (adding record to Persons table).

**Technical description**

I have a simple 2 object Table-Per-Type inheritance defined in an EF model.

***Entities***

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Person : User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

***Database***

```
public class MainDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        var configs = modelBuilder.Configurations;
        configs.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        configs.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
    }
}
```

***Configurations***

```
internal class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    internal UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Users");

        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.Password)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.Email)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);
    }
}
internal class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    internal PersonConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Persons");

        Property(x => x.FirstName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(16);
        Property(x => x.MiddleName)
            .IsOptional()
            .HasMaxLength(16);
        Property(x => x.LastName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(16);
    }
}
```

Necessary to consistently create linked (FK) objects in the DbSets, something like this:

```
    var db = new MainDataContext();
    var user = new User
    {
        Name = "someUser",
        Password = "somePassword",
        Email = "someEmail"
    };
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    // After some time in other some place
    var person = new Person
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        FirstName = "someFirstName",
        LastName = "someLastName"
    };
    db.Persons.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

After last SaveChanges DbEntityValidationError was caught: "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." There are 3 validation errors for required User's fields.

How to separately add entries to DbSets that are acociated by FK (inheritence)?

**UPDATE**

I found one solution. But for this you must remove the old user. I would like to do this without removing, because if the Users table would be associated with the other tables, then it will make it impossible to removing.

```
    var db = new MainDataContext();
    var user = new User
    {
        Name = "someUser",
        Password = "somePassword",
        Email = "someEmail"
    };
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    // After some time in other some place
    var person = new Person
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,
        Password = user.Password,
        Email = user.Email,
        FirstName = "someFirstName",
        LastName = "someLastName"
    };
    db.Users.Remove(user);
    db.Persons.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

But there was another problem - are generated a new Guid for the person object.

How to solve the problem without removing the old record of the user?

Comment: Because Person inherits from User, you must specify the Name, Password, and Email.  What does the database look like?  Does the Person table have all of the fields from the User table or just a FK to the user table.  If it is the later, your Entities are wrong.

Comment: @cadrell0 as I said earlier I use table-per-type (just FK to the user table) way to map tables to object hierarchies. Here is the [image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5522431/TPT.png) of the db diagram.

Comment: Then why does Person inherit from User?

Comment: Because that's needed by the logic of my application. Do you offer to do the opposite? It doesn't matter, the problem is not the case. Need to separately add records (objects) in the tables (DbSets) that are associated by foreign key (inheritance).

Comment: Your entities should match the format of your database. If your application needs to present the data differently, create domain classes (DTOs).

Comment: The validation is not causing the problem here. You could turn off validation but then the database would throw since you configured Password, Name and Email properties as required. This means that the database won't allow nulls. Since you are not setting corresponding properties you are trying effectively save nulls to non-nullable columns. Does your application allow these properties to be null? If yes, then the database probably should as well. If not, then you should never allow for them to be null in your app. If none of the above is true then you may need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: @jrummell and Pawel, sorry, but again you do not understand the problem. I'll try to explain even further. For example, the application requires the user to first registrate (ie fill username, password and e-mail) and then after confirmation of registration, fill his personal data (Persons table).

Comment: What happens if you just create a Person with all the fields set and call savechanges?

Comment: @alun everything is ok. New person is added to the db. But as I said I need to first add a user, and then supplement it by person.

Answer (score 1):

**After including usecase Update:**

You should not use inheritance here. You should use composition and one-to-one relationship between entities:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual UserInfo Information{get;set;}
}

internal class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    internal UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Users");

        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.Password)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);
        Property(x => x.Email)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);        
    }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    [ForeignKey("InfosUser")]
    [Key]
    public UserId {get;set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual User InfosUser {get;set;}
}

internal class UserInfoConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserInfo>
{
    internal UserInfoConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Persons");

        Property(x => x.FirstName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(16);
        Property(x => x.MiddleName)
            .IsOptional()
            .HasMaxLength(16);
        Property(x => x.LastName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(16);
        HasRequired(ui=>ui.InfosUser).WithOptional(u=>u.Information)
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
    var db = new MainDataContext();
    var user = new User
    {
        Name = "someUser",
        Password = "somePassword",
        Email = "someEmail"
    };
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    // After some time in other some place
    var user = db.GetPersonFromDb(Id);// Get early saved person from db
    var information = new UserInfo
    {
         FirstName = "someFirstName",
         LastName = "someLastName",
    }
    user.Information = information;
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Sorry, the solution doesn't fit, because I would like that FirstName and LastName columns were required in Persons table.

Comment: Could you describe your use-case? Why do you need to save half of data and then add some other data? It cannot be done in ef what do you want (except your workaround with deleting previous row), but i am sure that there is another way for your use-case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, honestly I used such approach already. But I want to use TFT inheritance and my question is about this.

Comment: You cannot change (upcast or downcast) type of entity in Entity Framework. It is limitation of EF.

Comment: Does it really means that the type changing? I just want to add Person object (after adding User object) with using the generated userId, but with keeping inheritance.

Comment: From EF point of view Person and User is two different types. You cannot change (or upcast) from User to Person or vice-versa. If you want to work with UserTable and PersonTable like with different tables you should not use inheritance between User and Person classes

Comment: Kirill, it seems you're right. But I want to be sure. What's about entity's state, attach, detach and etc? Is there any way to delete User entity and create Person with same ID?

Comment: Theoretically, you can remove          .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); and set Id. It will be saved. But in this case you should set default in database or create Id for every new inserted entity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the created object is not a Person object. If you insert the User.id value into the Person table you can then find the user as a Person and udpate them.

```
        Guid id;
        using (var db = new MainDataContext())
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                Name = "someUser",
                Password = "somePassword",
                Email = "someEmail"
            };
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            id = user.Id;
        }

        // After some time in other some place
        //pause here and insert the id GUID into the Person table

        using (var db = new MainDataContext())
        {
            var person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            person.FirstName = "someFirstName";
            person.LastName = "someLastName";
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Adding the id of the User to the Person table outside of EF achieves the upcast you desire. You can "promote" an object from User to Person with a direct database update.